# share a property among different instance of the same class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to share one parameter of a class among all the instances of this class, in objective-c?:

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject {
    NSString* shared; /** shared among instance (this is not, but defined somehow) **/
    NSString* non_shared; /** other parameters non shared **/
}
```

In the program then, each instance of Class1 has its own non_shared variables (as usual), but all access the same shared one (when one instance changes it all can see it).

One possibility is to hide the variable as a property and use a singleton in the setter/getter functions, but I don't know if there is a simple way.

Thanks,
 Edu

Answer (score 2):

Class variables (called `static` in many other OOP languages) are actually a bit of a pain in Objective-C. You have to declare a static global variable in the class' module (.m) file and reference that variable. You should add class-level getter/setters to encapsulate access to the static global variable. Your getter can alloc/init an object and put it in the variable if it is uninitialized before returning it.

If the static variable holds an instance (e.g. an `NSString` instance in your example), you need to make sure it doesn't get alloc/initialized more than once. Take a look at `dispatch_once` if you're on OS X 10.6 or greater to guarantee single initialization.